# C doubly linked list

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement (BST) with doubly linked list in C with loops.  but something I couldn't understand why one could is work as expected and the other is not.

look at first code which is working well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node* left;
  struct Node* right;
} Node;


typedef struct BST {
  Node* root;
}BST;



Node * createNode(int value) {
  Node * a= (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));
  a->left = NULL;
  a->right = NULL;
  a->data = value; 
  return a; 
}
void printBST(Node * bst) {
  if(bst == NULL) {return; } 
  printf("%d ", bst->data);
  printBST(bst->left);
  printBST(bst->right); 
}


Node* createRandomBST(size_t len){
  if(len == 0) {return NULL;}

  Node* tempBST = createNode(rand()%200);

  printf("   root: %d \n",  tempBST->data);

  Node* ptr_1;
  Node  *ptr_2;
  ptr_1 = tempBST;
  ptr_2 = tempBST;


  for(int  i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int value = i*i+22;
    tempBST = ptr_1;
    while (1)
    {
      
      if(value >= tempBST->data) {
        
        if(tempBST->right == NULL) {
          tempBST->right = createNode(value);
          printf("right-I: %d, value:%d \n", i, tempBST->data);
          break;
        }
        tempBST = tempBST ->right;

      }else {
         
        if(tempBST->left == NULL) {
          tempBST->left = createNode(value);
          printf("left-I: %d, value:%d \n", i, value);
          break;
        }   
        tempBST= tempBST->left;    
      }
    }
      
    
  }
return ptr_2;
}
```

Second  code which isn't working as expected.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node* left;
  struct Node* right;
} Node;


typedef struct BST {
  Node* root;
}BST;



Node * createNode(int value) {
  Node * a= (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));
  a->left = NULL;
  a->right = NULL;
  a->data = value; 
  return a; 
}
void printBST(Node * bst) {
  if(bst == NULL) {return; } 
  printf("%d ", bst->data);
  printBST(bst->left);
  printBST(bst->right); 
}

Node* createRandomBST(size_t len){
  if(len == 0) {return NULL;}

  Node* tempBST = createNode(rand()%200); //start by creating root node.

  printf("   root: %d \n",  tempBST->data); // print the root node

  Node* ptr_1; 
  Node  *ptr_2;
  ptr_1 = tempBST; // ptr_1 and ptr_2 are copy of the root node.
  ptr_2 = tempBST;


  for(int  i = 0; i < len; i++) {  // start the loop -- tempBST , ptr_1 and ptr_2 are all pointing to the root node 
    int value = i*i+22;    //the value needed to be inserted.
    tempBST = ptr_1;  // every time  need to insert a node it will  start from the root node.

    while (1)  //loop until insertion is happend 
    {
      
      if(value >= tempBST->data) {   //if the value greater than the root->data then go right 
         tempBST = tempBST ->right;  // now tempBST is pointing to tempBST->right not the root 
        if(tempBST == NULL) {       //if tempBST is null then the insertion will happened else loop with tempBST-> as the root..
          tempBST = createNode(value);     //if tempBST->right is empty insert the node.
          printf("right-I: %d, value:%d \n", i, tempBST->data);
          break; break;
        }
      }else { //if the value greater than the root->data then go left 

          tempBST = tempBST ->left; // now tempBST is pointing to tempBST->left not the root
          if(tempBST == NULL) {
          tempBST = createNode(value); //if tempBST->left is null then the insertion will happened else loop with tempBST-> as the root..
          printf("left-I: %d, value:%d \n", i, value);
          break; 
        }   
           
      }
    }
  }
return ptr_2;  //return  a pointer the root;
}





int main() {
  Node* tem; 
  tem = createRandomBST(20);
  printf("%d ", tem->data);
  printBST(tem);

}
```

I tried to debug it with GDB I couldn't understand the problem.
in the first code the printBST() print all the nodes but in the second one only the root is being printed

Comment: What are you throwing in there, what are you expecting, what are you getting?

Comment: A "BST with linked list", what beast is that ?

Comment: I am trying to get the same output as the first code because they are logically the same.

Comment: They are not. In the second option, you are allocating an orphaned node.

Comment: Describe a test case that reveals the issue, with detailed results.

Comment: when printing the BST(Binary search tree) with first one it is printing it all . but with the second one only the ROOT is being printed

Comment: "... because they are logically the same..." With a double linked list, node->next->prev is the node itself. With a BST, node->right->left is a "grandchild" node... They are not the same thing! QED

Comment: please look again at the code @Fe2O3 sorry there were a mistake in the second code which I mean else {
          tempBST = tempBST ->left;
        if(tempBST == NULL) {
          tempBST = createNode(value);
          printf("left-I: %d, value:%d \n", i, value);
          break;
        }

Comment: @RefugnicEternium could you explain more ?

Comment: A BST has no cycles.  A doubly linked list has cycles.  The statement that they are "logically the same" implies that you are ignoring certain details.  You might want to clarify what you mean.

Comment: In your code, I don't see anything that resembles a doubly-linked list.  In the second implementation, you never update `tmpBST->left` or `tmpBST->right` so the root has no children.  Hence, the print routine only prints one node because the tree at that point consists of only the root.

Comment: @WilliamPursell here is the explain>

Comment: @WilliamPursell , please look again at the code I have commented to what I am expecting from every line

Comment: @MAGEDAL-WARD You have comments like "//if tempBST is null then the insertion will happened", but there does not seem to be any code that puts this new node into the tree.  In other words, the insertion does not happen.

Comment: @WilliamPursell when i assigned tempBST = createNode(value); will store the node int tempBST which is pointing to last leaf in the tree. if you looked at the first code it worked fine .

Comment: @MAGEDAL-WARD It works in the first code because you assign to `tempBST->right` and `tempBST->left`.  In the second code, you fail to do that.  The new node is never inserted into the tree.

Comment: Yeah thanks I got it, when I thought I assigned it using tempBST =tempBST->right; But I just realized that right was null.